# Using the webclient to upload a file 405 error problem

Tags: c#, webclient

```
VS C# 2005
```

I am using the code below to upload a file to a server running windows IIS 5.1.

I am just testing on our local server running windows XP. However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
The remote server returned an error (405) Method Not Allowed
```

I am sure this is a IIS problem maybe something to so with permissions. However, I am configured IIS to allow read, write, and directory browsing.

The config.xml file I am trying to upload is located in the same directory as the executable.

```
   private void upload_config_to_server()
   {
        Uri url = new Uri("http://10.10.10.3/softphone/config.xml");

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        if (!wc.IsBusy)
        {                
            try
            {
                wc.UploadFile(url, null, "config.xml");
            }
            catch (WebException webex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Web Exception {0}", webex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only registered file types can accept requests with a POST method in IIS. See this "[How to resolve HTTP 405](http://www.somacon.com/p126.php)" article for more details.

Also, for posting the file, you need to make sure that server side script handles this upload properly, if you want it to appear in the folder you're uploading. Your URL (first argument in the wc.UploadFile) should be that server side script that handles the upload.

Comment: I have done everything with setting the IIS. However, the OK button remained grayed out. So I couldn't do anything with that. However, I managed to get it working by passing the "PUT" parameter in the wc.UpLoadFile. Why does it work with the "PUT"? Thanks.

Comment: HTTP PUT is just another method, along with GET, POST, DELETE, etc. It is used solely for file upload, and URI is the target where the file will be saved. I guess this is exactly what you were looking for, instead of proper handling of POSTs...

Comment: Also make sure you have an **action method** for `POST` with **correct routing** in your controller.