# c# .net upload image file to website 405 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, file-upload, image-uploading

Similar questions were asked, and i'm trying to implement base on them. However, i am not able to **Upload** an image file to my **Website**. I'm getting 405 error.

Here is my code:

```
//model
public class UploadModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase imageFile { get; set; }
}

//View
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imageFile, new { type = "file", accept = "image/*" })

//Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadModel model)
{
    if (model.imageFile != null && model.imageFile.ContentLength > 0) //not null, gets right file
    {
        string web = "https://myWebSite.com/images/"; //without www
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), model.imageFile.FileName); 

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        byte[] responseArray = client.UploadFile(@web, path); //Here i get 405 error
        String response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
        client.Dispose();
    }
    return View();
}
```

When i call `WebClient.UploadFile` method i get 405 error. Web url is correct, the website does not require credentials. Then why i am getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to upload a file uploaded to your webserver?

Comment: You might want to take a look here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Comment: yes, what do you mean by "upload a file uploaded"? i'd like to upload an image file to my web server.

Comment: @antoinedelia i've read that several times, but as i observe it does not upload an image, at least there is no any kind of web url.

Comment: @stuartd can you refer question that is duplicate of that?

Comment: can you share an html form?

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak the link's at the top of the page - [Using the webclient to upload a file 405 error problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163444/using-the-webclient-to-upload-a-file-405-error-problem)

Comment: @snnbrn what do you mean by sharing an html form(sorry, i'm new to whole html and mvc)

Comment: I will share an html example to send files.

Comment: @stuartd i've already examined that and reexamine when you refer, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new 
                                       { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imageFile, new { type = "file", accept = "image/*" })     
}

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak it's the exact same error you get from the same code. You say it doesn't solve your problem - have you checked that the server has a script map for the extension of the file you're uploading, as in the linked page [How to resolve a HTTP 405 error](http://www.somacon.com/p126.php)?

Comment: sample http://www.aurigma.com/upload-suite/developers/aspnet-mvc/how-to-upload-files-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imageFile, new { type = "file", accept = "image/*" }) } `

Comment: @stuartd yes, i meant by examined referring question, it is the link given in accepted answer.

Comment: So can you show the script map that's defined for the file extension you're uploading?

Comment: @snnbrn i've examined similar implemantation that you've sent (like http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/ ). However, with them there are something i don't get, that is why i'm using WebClient.

Comment: @snnbrn for example in these implementations there is a line `string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));` i'm not getting that. I need to give my website's path and i've `HttpPostedFileBase` object. At these implementations i couldn't understand how to use them.

Comment: if @snnbrn or any of you can explain how to upload file to website in a different way(i.e.in the ways that you've sent) or give a reference which explains clearly i'd really appreciate. Because i really couldn't find out.